# Clang complains that a POD class is actually non-POD

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm, variadic-functions

update: I've modified the code here so that you can just plug it right in and try to compile.

Clang 3.4.1 (LLVM 3.4) complains that my class is not a POD type ( which as far as I can tell most certainly is ) when used in a variadic function. G++ has no problem compiling this.

This class is POD even by C++03's standard:

- it contains only PODS as members
- has no user-defined destructor
- has no user-defined copy assignment operator
- has no nonstatic members of pointer-to-member type

And C++11's rules for what is "POD" was relaxed, so what's going on here?

About the code: This is a template class for a vector (as in vector graphics), and the variadic function is just used to fill an array with some arbitrary data.

My class header file:

```
template<typename TYPE>
class Vec3t;

typedef Vec3t<float> Vec3f;

template<typename TYPE>
class Vec3t {
public:
    Vec3t<TYPE>( void ){}
    Vec3t<TYPE>( const TYPE nx, const TYPE ny, const TYPE nz ){}

    Vec3t<TYPE> operator-(void) const{}

    Vec3t<TYPE> operator*( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other ) const{}
    Vec3t<TYPE> operator*( const TYPE val ) const{}
    Vec3t<TYPE>& operator*=( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other ){}
    Vec3t<TYPE>& operator*=( const TYPE val ){}

    Vec3t<TYPE> operator+( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other ) const{}
    Vec3t<TYPE> operator+( const TYPE val ) const{}
    Vec3t<TYPE>& operator+=( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other ){}
    Vec3t<TYPE>& operator+=( const TYPE val ){}

    Vec3t<TYPE> operator-( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other ) const{}
    Vec3t<TYPE> operator-( const TYPE val ) const{}
    Vec3t<TYPE>& operator-=( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other ){}
    Vec3t<TYPE>& operator-=( const TYPE val ){}

    Vec3t<TYPE> operator/( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other ) const{}
    Vec3t<TYPE> operator/( const TYPE val ) const{}
    Vec3t<TYPE>& operator/=( const TYPE val ){}
    Vec3t<TYPE>& operator/=( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other ){}

    bool operator==( const Vec3t<TYPE> &b ) const {}
    bool operator==( const TYPE b ) const {}
    bool operator!=( const Vec3t<TYPE> &b ) const {}
    bool operator!=( const TYPE b ) const {}

    Vec3t<TYPE>& Set( const TYPE a, const TYPE b, const TYPE c ){}
    Vec3t<TYPE>& Set( const TYPE a, const TYPE b ){}

    void Cross( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other, Vec3t<TYPE> &out ) const{}

    TYPE Dot( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other ) const{}

    Vec3t<TYPE> PerpCCW_ZAxis( void ){}
    Vec3t<TYPE> PerpCW_ZAxis( void ){}

    float Len( void ) const{}
    void Zero( void ){}

    static void Cross( const Vec3t<TYPE> &other, const Vec3t<TYPE> &u, Vec3t<TYPE> &out ){}

    Vec3f Normalize( void ){}
    Vec3f Rotation( TYPE angle ){}
    float DegreesBetween( const Vec3f &other ){}
    float RadiansBetween( const Vec3f &other ){}
    Vec3f Rotate( float angle, const bool inRadians = false ){}
    static float Len( const Vec3f &other ){}

public:
    TYPE        x,y,z;
};

template< typename TYPE >
void FillArray( const std::size_t count, TYPE* var, ... ) {
    va_list vargs;
    va_start( vargs, var );

    for ( std::size_t i=0; i<count; i++ ) {
        var[i] = va_arg( vargs, TYPE ); // ** THIS IS THE LINE CLANG ERRS ON ** //
    }

    va_end( vargs );
}
```

My variadic function header file:

```
#include <cstdarg>

template< typename TYPE >
void FillArray( const std::size_t count, TYPE* var, ... ) {
    va_list vargs;
    va_start( vargs, var );

    for ( std::size_t i=0; i<count; i++ ) {
        var[i] = va_arg( vargs, TYPE ); // ** THIS IS THE LINE CLANG ERRS ON ** //
    }

    va_end( vargs );
}
```

Clang's error:
    error: second argument to 'va_arg' is of non-POD type 'Vec3t' [-Wnon-pod-varargs]

An example program using these that causes the error in Clang:
    #include "fillarray.h"

```
int main ( void ) {
    Vec3t<float> v[2];
    FillArray< Vec3t<float> >( 2, v, 0.4f, 0.5f);
}
```

compile with:
     clang++ x.cpp -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/4.8 -std=gnu++11

Comment: For the purposes of debugging this (and a more succinct question), I suggest chopping out as much as you can from your class definition.

Comment: That is odd that it suggests `Vec3t` is a type at all, when it is really a template.

Comment: for the record, I typedef Vec3t<float> to Vec3f. Although I doubt that has any bearing.

Comment: If you are unsure whether a type is POD or not, then, use static_assert with std::is_pod.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

§12.1/7:

> A default constructor is trivial if it is not user-provided and...
>
> Otherwise, the default constructor is *non-trivial*.

The default constructor you have declared is non-trivial by definition.

§9/3:

> A *trivial class* is a class that has a trivial default constructor (12.1) and is trivially copyable.

Since the default constructor is non-trivial, the class is not trivial.

§9/10:

> A *POD struct* is a non-union class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class...

Since the class is not trivial, it doesn't qualify as POD.  In order to make it POD, you'd have to get rid of the default constructor.

Comment: Yea, that was the problem. Where did you copy this info from? Last I heard a printout or PDF to the actual C++ ISO standard costs money. all I've been able to find is just random tidbits with googling, usually found here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @zeroth: I have a copy of the standard.  It was like $30 from ANSI, IIRC.

Comment: @zeroth: http://webstore.ansi.org/RecordDetail.aspx?sku=INCITS%2fISO%2fIEC+14882-2012

Comment: @zeroth: You can always get the working draft for free, linked to from [here](http://isocpp.org/).

Comment: @zeroth As you're using C++11 you don't need to get rid of the default constructor. You can use the "= default" syntax to make it trivial. This allows you to have other non-default and non-trivial constructors. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Modification_to_the_definition_of_plain_old_data

Comment: @Adam: `= default` doesn't let you have a custom default constructor, though.  You're still getting rid of it.  One wouldn't normally add a constructor unless it did something over and above what the auto-generated one does.

Comment: @cHao Assuming I didn't make any typos, try compiling these two bits of code: `class foo {public: int x; foo(int y):x(y){}}; foo one;` and `class bar {public: int x; bar(int y):x(y){} bar() = default; }; bar two;`. It should fail on the `foo one;` statement because there is no default constructor for foo, but `bar two;` should compile.

Comment: @Adam: Should, and almost certainly does, in any compiler that's worth a damn.  :)  But the second you look at `two.x`, you have UB;  `x` in both cases would have an indeterminate value.  I'm assuming that the `{}` in the example is just a placeholder for actual code, like all the other `{}`s -- even the one for the other constructor -- and that it'd put the object into some known state.

Comment: @cHao The point is that foo is not POD, but because bar has a trivial default constructor it is POD.